# How can I delete a newline character in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a little problem with a small script. The textfile has a lot of entries like:

```
permission-project1-admin
permission-project2-admin
....
```

The script looks like this (indeed, it is an awful one but still helps me):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat adminpermission.txt); do
    permission=$(echo $i | cut -f1)

printf "dn:$permission,ou=groups,dc=domain,dc=com \n"
printf "objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames \n"
printf "objectclass: top \n"
printf "description: \n"
printf "cn:$permission \n\n"
done
```

The output looks fine, but because the textfile has a newline character at the end, the first line of printf is devided into two lines like:

```
dn:permission-project1-admin
,ou=groups,dc=domain,dc=com
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectclass: top
description:
cn:permission-project1-admin
```

My question is, how I can eliminate the newline character between the first two lines?

Comment: `echo -n` omits the trailing newline.

Comment: just remove `-n` in first printf output

Answer (score 3):

[Do it correctly in the first place.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

```
while read permission rest
do
  ...
done < adminpermission.txt
```

Also, heredocs.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(echo $i | tr -d "\n" | cut -f1)
```

Comment: This line of code didn't work for me. The output was the same as above. But many thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your your `adminpermission.txt` contains DOS style carriage returns? Your code will strip linefeeds, but depending on how you view the output, carriage returns can break the lines like you describe.

You can try

```
mv adminpermission.txt backup.txt
tr -d '\r' < backup.txt > adminpermission.txt
```

to convert to UNIX EOL, and then run your script again.

Comment: This worked for me. The adminpermission file contained DOS style carriage. After converting the file into UNIX EOL, it worked fine. Many thanks.

Comment: That's great! Make sure to mark the answer as Accepted by clicking the checkbox next to it, to award points and help people find the right answer in the future.